# Add option into select in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

I want to add option into select drop down. In this I take value for new option from another view that contain text box.  Please help me out in CodeIgniter.

One view contain text box.
I get this value through `$this->input->post('name')`.
Now I want to add this value in select drop down as new option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ajax,j query with this then it would be very easy. How, send the post values to ajax success and append to the drop down.

Or take a view and regenerates the dop down values in page and by the help of j query paste this page to your original page by the help of .html()